# How to acces my Android phone on OpenSuSe

Tags: android, opensuse

I want to learn to develop for android.

But in a part of the course where I have to install the application on my phone, I can not continue because I do not know how to make my phone visible in linux (I found tutorials for Mac and for Windows)
Does anyone know how to do for linux?

**What I do have:**

- OpenSuSE 42.2
- Android Studio
- My phone in development mode (KitKat 4.4)
- Samsung SM-G313MU

after following the comment I’m getting this:

```
:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools> adb usb
error: insufficient permissions for device
```

also try this with more privileges:

```
:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools> sudo adb usb
root's password:
error: insufficient permissions for device
```

Comment: Often it just works, if you have USB debugging enabled on the device (step #1 at [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#setting-up)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out it all about permissions. So I did the same as root. Maybe later will figure out to to do  it as my user.